# How to get the id of the checked person from jQuery to ASP.NET Core 6 MVC controller?

Tags: jquery, controller, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0, vote

I want to create a voting system in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC:

[image]

I have a jQuery script that verify is only one checkbox is checked of the class name. After I press the button, I want to display the selected options. The image and the name of candidate.

How can I get details from the database (using Entity Framework) for the selected option? I suppose that I need somehow to get the selected one in controller. I tried but I didn't have any success.

```
@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".ceo").on("change", function () {
            if ($(".ceo:checked").length == 1) {
                $(".ceo").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $(".ceo:checked").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            else {
                $(".ceo").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });

        $(".productmanager").on("change", function () {
            if ($(".productmanager:checked").length == 1) {
                $(".productmanager").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $(".productmanager:checked").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            else {
                $(".productmanager").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you share more code about how you display your checkbox?

Comment: "How can I get details from the database (using Entity Framework) for the selected option? "How about try to use `asp-route-{value}`? Then you can get the id in the controller.  You can read [Anchor Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to know more.

Comment: Where to use asp-route-{value} ?

Comment: Here describe [asp-route-{value}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0#asp-route-value) clearly, you can refer to it.